# How to manipulate the value of a pandas multiindex on a specific level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Given a dataframe with row and column multiindex, how would you copy a row index "object" and manipulate a specific index value on a chosen level? Ultimately I would like to add a new row to the dataframe with this manipulated index.

Taking this dataframe df as an example:

```
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'], [1,2,3,4]], names=['cInd1', 'cInd2'])
row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['2010','2011','2009'],['a','r','t'],[45,34,35]], names=["rInd1", "rInd2", 'rInd3'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=row_index, columns=col_index)
df

cInd1                A                   B               
cInd2                1    2    3    4    1    2    3    4
rInd1 rInd2 rInd3                                        
2010  a     45     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2011  r     34     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009  t     35     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I would like to take the index of the first row, manipulate the "rInd2" value and use this index to insert another row.

Pseudo code would be something like this:

```
#Get Index
idx = df.index[0]
#Manipulate Value
idx[1] = "L" #or idx["rInd2"]

#Make new row with new index
df.loc[idx, slice(None)] = None
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
cInd1                A                   B               
cInd2                1    2    3    4    1    2    3    4
rInd1 rInd2 rInd3                                        
2010  a     45     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2011  r     34     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009  t     35     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2010  L     45     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Is there a way to do the same procedure with column index?

Thanks

Comment: @HenryEcker no it's not "really unclear". 3 level row index, 2 level column index, data is 4x8

Comment: @Martin can you include the output from `df.head().to_dict()` in your question? this will make it easier for us to reproduce your sample df because as @Henry Ecker mentioned, although we can make an educated case about how your dataframe is structured, it's not entirely clear about how `cInd2` and `cInd1` align with the rest of your dataframe.

Comment: @HenryEcker I updated the question, hope it is more clear that way?

Comment: Yes the code constructor and standard pandas output is very helpful. Thank you!